# How the browser treats static file,downloadable file,json,xml

Tags: browser

Very basic question.Here it goes.
The client hits a url in the server.The server can send content in the form of

1. static files(javascript/html).
2. xml/json(predominantly the purpose of this file is to return some DATA to the client).
3. Downloadable file-kinda zip files.For this part the server needs to set the content type property to something to let the client know that it wants this file to download of something.

My question is how does the browser differentiate between the static files and api responses(form of xml/json/string) ??

Thanks,
Gully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

There's no such thing as a "file" in HTTP.  There are requests and responses, each of which consist of headers and content.  The response content may be the contents of what was a "file" on the server, and may be intended to be treated as a "file" on the client (such as downloading a .zip file), but the response itself is not a file.  The way that the server indicates to the client that something *should* be a file is through the HTTP headers.

Specifically the two headers you're talking about are:

- Content-Type
- Content-Disposition

The first tells the client (browser) what kind of data it's receiving.  There are [lots of examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type), and most browsers understand what to do with most common types.  The second can be used to suggest to the client that the content should be saved as a file rather than displayed.  For example, the Content-Type might be for an image, and by default a browser will just display an image.  But you can add a Content-Disposition header to indicate that the image is an "attachment" and even suggest a file name for it, instructing the browser to save the file (or prompt the user asking to save the file) instead of displaying it.

Comment: Thanks @David .So if I am trying to sort out files received from a server ,is the best possible way to check the content-type which would  indicate if the response is a json/xml or static files.

Comment: @SoumyadeepGanguly: The Content-Type would (should) indicate the type of data (or content, rather) being received.  From the client's perspective there's no difference between "dynamic" or "static" files.  It's just content received in a response.  Whether that content was constructed from a file, a set of files, data from a database, etc. makes no difference client-side.